# Debug log for RPC access log

Tags: json-rpc

How can I enable RPC access debug log on my bitcoind. My application calls some commands to the bitcoind via RPC. I want to see all of RPC accesses with their parameters like command name and caller IP address as well if possible.

Answer (score 6):

I found the way. I confirmed the logs are saved as I expected.

**bitcoin.conf**

```
debug=mempool
debug=rpc
```

Comment: Another way to enable debug log:  put '-debug=<category>' as the command line parameter of bitcoind, <category> can be coindb, db, mempool, rpc and so on. For example:  bitcoind -debug=rpc

Answer (score 1):

The debugging from adding `debug=rpc` to `bitcoind.conf` is fairly terse:

```
2023-03-24T11:24:48Z ThreadRPCServer method=getblockchaininfo user=bitcoin
2023-03-24T11:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer method=getblockchaininfo user=bitcoin
2023-03-24T11:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer method=getrawmempool user=bitcoin
2023-03-24T11:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer method=getmempoolentry user=bitcoin
2023-03-24T11:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer method=getmempoolentry user=bitcoin
2023-03-24T11:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer method=getmempoolentry user=bitcoin
2023-03-24T11:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer method=getmempoolentry user=bitcoin
2023-03-24T11:25:02Z ThreadRPCServer method=getmempoolentry user=bitcoin
```